# Three js wireframe sphere svg

Tags: svg, three.js

I'm trying to build the following wireframe spheres with three.js. It's important, that I can export them as well structured SVG files with singles lines (vertical and horizontal), so I can plot them with my Axidraw drawing machine.

[image: sphere]

I've used the following setup to get a wireframe sphere with solid white surfaces:

```
let geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(1, 32, 16);
let material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xd3d3d3 });

let mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(mesh);

let wireframe = new THREE.WireframeGeometry(geometry);
let line = new THREE.LineSegments(wireframe);
line.material.color.setHex(0x000000);
scene.add(line);

scene.add(new THREE.AmbientLight('#fff'));
```

But when I export the sphere now with the Three.js SVGRenderer I'm getting a SVG sphere with weird single fragments and not as wished single horizontal and vertical rings/lines:

[image: sphere fragments]

does anyone have an idea how I can achieve a better structured SVG file of a wireframe sphere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you please try it with this setup? It just adds an instance of `LineSegments` to the scene (and no mesh). Also notice the usage of `EdgesGeometry` instead of `WireframeGeometry`.

```js
let camera, scene, renderer, lines;

init();
animate();

function init() {

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 33, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 50 );
    camera.position.z = 5;

    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0, 0, 0 );

    renderer = new THREE.SVGRenderer();
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

    //

    const geometry = new THREE.SphereBufferGeometry(1, 32, 16);
    const material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({ color: 0xd3d3d3 });

    const wireframe = new THREE.EdgesGeometry(geometry);
    lines = new THREE.LineSegments(wireframe, material);
    scene.add(lines);

    //

    window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

}

function onWindowResize() {

    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

}

function animate() {

    let time = performance.now() / 1000;

    lines.rotation.x = time / 3;
    lines.rotation.z = time / 4;

    renderer.render( scene, camera );
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );

}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #000;
  margin: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

svg {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.116.1/build/three.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.116.1/examples/js/renderers/Projector.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.116.1/examples/js/renderers/SVGRenderer.js"></script>
```

Comment: that's the solution I was looking for. Thanks for your great answer!
One additional question: is there a way to only see the wireframes in the "foreground"? In other words, is there a possibility to fill the surfaces with solid white so you can't look though the sphere and it also effect the resulting svg?

Comment: I'm afraid `SVGRenderer` does not provide this kind of flexibility.